# pandas: series from index using ffill/bfill/nearest values from another index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

Say I have a DatetimeIndex `idx1`:

```
['2023-06-02',
'2023-06-04',
'2023-06-06',
'2023-06-08',
'2023-06-10',
'2023-06-12']
```

and another `idx2`:

```
['2023-06-03',
'2023-06-08']
```

I want to construct a series with `idx1` as its index, and the values being the nearest index value from `idx2`, so:

```
2023-06-02    '2023-06-03'
2023-06-04    '2023-06-03'
2023-06-06    '2023-06-08'
2023-06-08    '2023-06-08'
2023-06-10    '2023-06-08'
2023-06-12    '2023-06-08'
```

or e.g. bfill:

```
2023-06-02             NaN
2023-06-04    '2023-06-03'
2023-06-06    '2023-06-03'
2023-06-08    '2023-06-08'
2023-06-10    '2023-06-08'
2023-06-12    '2023-06-08'
```

or ffill:

```
2023-06-02    '2023-06-03'
2023-06-04    '2023-06-08'
2023-06-06    '2023-06-08'
2023-06-08    '2023-06-08'
2023-06-10             NaN
2023-06-12             NaN
```

basically any of the available options from `pandas.Series.reindex`.

How would I construct such a series?

Similar question for other index dtypes like numeric index etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) for *numeric* indexes:

1. Turn your indexes into series ([`pd.Index.to_series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html)) and add a name ([`Series.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html)).
2. Use `pd.merge_asof`, merging on the indexes and setting the `direction` parameter to the desired value, and select column `s2` (i.e. the values for `idx2`).

Using a list comprehension:

```
s1 = idx1.to_series().rename('s1')
s2 = idx2.to_series().rename('s2')

nearest, bfill, ffill = [(pd.merge_asof(s1, s2, 
                                        direction=direction, 
                                        left_index=True, 
                                        right_index=True)['s2']) 
                         for direction in ['nearest','backward','forward']]
```

Prints:

```
nearest

2023-06-02   2023-06-03
2023-06-04   2023-06-03
2023-06-06   2023-06-08
2023-06-08   2023-06-08
2023-06-10   2023-06-08
2023-06-12   2023-06-08
Name: s2, dtype: datetime64[ns]

bfill

2023-06-02          NaT
2023-06-04   2023-06-03
2023-06-06   2023-06-03
2023-06-08   2023-06-08
2023-06-10   2023-06-08
2023-06-12   2023-06-08
Name: s2, dtype: datetime64[ns]

ffill

2023-06-02   2023-06-03
2023-06-04   2023-06-08
2023-06-06   2023-06-08
2023-06-08   2023-06-08
2023-06-10          NaT
2023-06-12          NaT
Name: s2, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Be aware of the following statement from the docs (capitals in the original):

> The data MUST be ordered. Furthermore this must be a numeric column, such as datetimelike, integer, or float.